# How to open an Order for an account without a contract

Tags: community, administration, user-admin

In SF when I try to open an order it lets me open one only on a certain contract.
I want to override this and open an order on an account without the contract issue.
For example:
User ABC - Order 1
Basically I don't need the contract entity but I don't want to delete it maybe for future use.
How can I do it?
Thanks,
udi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should just be able to make the contract field not required on the Order page layout, by default it is set to required:
[image]